# angular directive dom manipulation

Tags: angularjs

I need to manipulate DOM based on an event that does not come from the page itself (not mouseover, click, etc.).  The event comes from a listener on the network.

What is the best practice for putting my listener?  Ideally I'd create a directive to do the work but I don't see how that would work, because the event doesn't come from the element itself.

An alternative is to have the listener in the controller or service, which gets the element by ID and does the manipulation.  I have implemented it this way, but it doesn't "feel" right to have view information down in the controller or service.

Another alternative I can think of is to write a directive that isn't attached to a particular field, and inject that directive into the service, which configures the listener.  This keeps the view information out of the service.

Any ideas for the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a directive, which handles the DOM manipulation, and a service, which handles the communication. Inject the service into the directive.

This way, the directive is subscribing to events from the service. The service is handling the communication with the server, and emitting events out to any subscribed directives or controllers.

Would that work?

Comment: Seems like a reasonable approach, I will give it a shot.